# Email provider - suggestions needed

Tags: email, google-workspace

We are looking for a good way to have email support. In theory, we need to allow end-users to send emails directly to support and careers. i.e. support@domain_name_here.com and careers@domain_name_here.com.

Second, we need to provide emails to our staff. So each staff member has their own email address. i.e. joe@domain_name_here.com, meghan@domain_name_here.com, etc.

[Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) is one that we are considering. However, they are charging $50 per user, per year. Not so bad, considering the quality and the features they offer.

However, there are also cheaper alternatives. i.e. my domain registrar offers an email plan for $20 / year / 10 emails. [Go Daddy](http://www.godaddy.com/email/email-hosting.aspx?ci=8973) has a number of plans and still a lot more affordable than Google Apps. So far Namecheap and Go Daddy are the only ones I have looked at for email plans.

Is it worth signing up with Google Apps? Or are there better alternatives?

Your thoughts?

Comment: Google Apps is free for companies < 50. how many are you?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails and Heroku?

Comment: My thought is that this is completely off topic for SO.  Migrating.

Comment: Apneadiving: currently less than 50 who need email address'. Will: Ooops, my mistake with the tagging. Thanks for migrating the topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Google Apps is one that we are considering. However, they are charging $50 per user, per year. Not so bad, considering the quality and the features they offer.

It's free for less than 50 users which makes it a great solution if you're working with a small company.

[Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/apps/email_hosting/rackspace_email/) Email hosting is fairly cheap coming in around $24 a year per user versus $50 with google.

Comment: How is Rackspace's spam filtering and webmail interface though? Oh, and the $50/user/year is correct: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/gmail.html --but it's for the entire Google Apps Suite, not just Gmail.

Comment: Click the link to rackspace email, the very first picture you see is the email interface =)

Comment: or even better, go here and test it : https://email.rackspace.com/a/webmail.php?wsid=fWq2XdXNlcjEwMDIxQG53LWRlbW8ubWFpbHRydXN0LmNvbSxlQlQ0TGp2YjZZck9vTzV6

Comment: Not bad. No labels, but some people prefer folders over labels anyway. Much better than Squirrel Mail. =P But what about spam filtering? Also, the demo link should be: https://email.rackspace.com/a/ext/demo/launch.php

Comment: Since Google Apps offers a free version for less than 50 accounts/users. I am also assuming that the privacy policy is still at par with the paid version right? i.e. hoping google or any of it's staff don't prowl into our emails

Comment: +1 for gmail. its awesome. I use that for my various domains,etc.

Comment: Google's not likely to spy on your emails (their software does automatically scan emails to display contextual advertising for the free version though), or at least less likely than other companies.

Comment: Spying on your accounts isn't an issue unless you're doing something illegal or the government is after you. If you're supporting less than 50 users, just use gmail. You'll save time, money, effort, and not have to lose any sleep over this.

Answer (score 2):

I've migrated all my e-mail clients to Google Apps. They are all on the free version (up-to 50 Users, not as much space and not as high as a guarantee for uptime).

50 Users doesn't include groups / aliases
You still get the normal gmail space of about 10GB
The uptime is still over 99.9%

Since '07, I've only had my clients call me two , maybe three times with issues. I've got about two dozen clients on google apps. The service is solid.

A couple of the things I like, you can activesync for cell phones, so calendar and contacts on most all smartphones. You've got calendar and contact sharing, and I believe they've pushed out the ability to share inboxes. So you are really getting a full exchange-style mail services .. for free.

On top of mail/calendar/contacts you get a private area for documents a sites ( like a wiki ). Their service is really top notch I can't praise it more really :)